# Can't get justify-content: space-between to work in Bootstrap framework

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

How can I get the below snippet to look like this:

[image]

So that the items are evenly spaced, and the first item has no empty space on the left & the last item has no empty space on the right. Similar to what MS Word can do:

> Full-justification
>
> All lines in a paragraph are expanded so they are neat against both
>   the left and right margins.
>   To expand the line, space has to be added, between words and
>   characters, to fill out the line.

In the code snippit below, there is lots of purple space to the left of the first item, I want to remove this.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  margin: 55px 10px;
  display: flex; 
  // align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #6495ed;
}
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

### UPDATE

@kukkuz answer below solves the snippit but I also had to add the below to get it to work with twitter Bootstrap.  Bootstrap was adding `:before` & `:after` elements that were messing things up for me.

[image]

Removing them got it working for me, but I would recommend using a more specific selector that `ul` otherwise you could mess things up with Bootstrap.

FYI -  I was using Bootstrap from this CDN, v3.3.7:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/dist/css/bootstrap.css

```
ul:before { 
    content: none;
}
ul:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: +100 for the use of `rebeccapurple`. http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2014/06/19/rebeccapurple/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset the user-agent/browser `padding` of `ul` element - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  margin: 55px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: stretch;*/
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #6495ed;
}
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beat me too it :)

Comment: @kukkuz, that makes sense but it didn't work for me, I realise it was because I was using Bootstrap and there were `:before` & `:after` elements messing things up for me.  I had to add `ul:before { content: none; } ul:after { content: none; }` to fix it, Can you add that to your answer, just in case it helps someone else?

Comment: are you sure its coming from bootstrap... I tried adding bootstrap css and couldn't find the `after`/`before` styles..

Comment: @kukkuz, yea, It's probably because I also had classes `nav navbar-nav` on the `ul`, sorry should have been more specific in my question, just didn't suspect Bootstrap at all

Comment: ohh, now I see why the pseudos where there :)